# Can't copy files to folder due to space issue after mand mount

Tags: mount, disk-usage, tmpfs

I tried doing mandatory mount using the following the command

```
mount -t tmpfs -o mand,size=1m tmpfs ./FileLockFail/
```

Now when I am trying to copy a folder to the mounted directory, its giving me error

```
cp -r data/ FileLockFail/
```

Error :

```
cp: error writing 'FileLockFail/data/folder2/file_1.txt': No space left on device
cp: error writing 'FileLockFail/data/folder2/file_2.txt': No space left on device
cp: error writing 'FileLockFail/data/folder2/file_3.txt': No space left on device
cp: error writing 'FileLockFail/data/folder1/file_3.txt': No space left on device
cp: error writing 'FileLockFail/data/folder1/file_1.txt': No space left on device
cp: error writing 'FileLockFail/data/folder1/file_2.txt': No space left on device
```

This is the output of `df -h` which shows I definitely have space

```
[root@himanshu/]# df -h
Filesystem                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                               3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                  3.8G   17M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                                  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/ol-root                     35G   19G   17G  53% /
/dev/mapper/frel-cache                  40G  318M   40G   1% /opt/FBR
/dev/sda1                             1014M  366M  649M  37% /boot
tmpfs                                  767M     0  767M   0% /run/user/0
//aws.amazon.com.compute.ecr           20T   18T  2.5T  88% /root/media
tmpfs                                  1.0M   16K 1008K   2% /FileLockFail
```

Comment: How large are the files you're copying?

Comment: 5 MBs, it used to work until yesterday

Comment: `/FileLockFail` has `1.0 M` ... that seems not like you have much space....

Comment: but tmfs can resize itself right?

Comment: What do you think the **size** option of the mount comment you wrote stands for ?

Comment: Yeah I researched about it and got to know about that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man tmpfs` would tell you that the **size** option you used when mounting

> Specify an **upper limit** on the size of the filesystem

You specified an upper limit of 1 M, no surprise that there is not enough space for copying your 5 M files.

In order to change this limit, either mount it with an appropriate value for the size option or, `mount -o remount` as suggested by the man pages :

> During a remount operation (mount -o remount), the filesystem size can
> be changed (without losing the existing contents of the filesystem).

---

BTW, a tmpfs does not strictly speaking "*resizes itself*" the amount of memory it consumes is however adjusted :

> The filesystem consumes only as much physical memory and swap space as
> is required to store the current contents of the filesystem.